# pandas exportation to_csv and excel column format misinterpretation

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My goal is to export a dataframe object into a csv file. I use pandas to do it.

My problem is that when I read my csv file, some columns have different format than what I expected.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas

results = [('company A','+39 0584 383468','2-10'),('company B','+590690610966','2-10'),('company C','+18093494353','11-50')]

df = pandas.DataFrame(results, columns=['name', 'phone', 'employees'])
```

When I run:

```
print(df)
```

I get:

```
        name            phone employees
0  company A  +39 0584 383468      2-10
1  company B    +590690610966      2-10
2  company C     +18093494353     11-50
```

Which is what I want.

But when I export to a csv file:

```
df.to_csv('./test.csv', sep = ',', index = False)
```

And go to `./test.csv` and check my csv file. I get:

[image]

As you can see, `phone` and `employees` changed. I wanted them to be kept as strings. But instead it got formatted into weird floating numbers and date format.

Why is that? How can I make my `test.csv` file exactly the same as the output `df` in `pandas`?

Edit: when I run `print(df.dtypes)`

```
name         object
phone        object
employees    object
dtype: object
```

Also weird, when I open back that same `test.csv` file into pandas, the format is correct:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("test.csv")
print(df)
```

I get:

```
        name            phone employees
0  company A  +39 0584 383468      2-10
1  company B    +590690610966      2-10
2  company C     +18093494353     11-50
```

Comment: isn't that just an excel default formatting? Like how it reads a particular column same way pandas try to predict the datatype of a column value when you use `read_csv()` on a csv file. Try to open it on a plain text (use notepad) and your desired format is still there. The encoding is correct basically, the interpretation of the application you are using is not (excel).

Comment: Does [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/568429/excel-csv-import-treating-quoted-strings-of-numbers-as-numeric-values-not-strin) on Super User fix the problem?

Comment: For the `phone` just expand the column size manually and weird floating numbers  should go away.

Comment: Can you try this `df['employee'] = df['employee'].map(lambda x: '"{}"'.format(x))`

Comment: @Joe How can you correct the misinterpretation from excel?

Comment: The default encoding it reads is Windows (ANSI).

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out, your issue is that your spreadsheet is auto-interpreting your phone numbers as numeric. To hint to other applications that they should treat these as text and not numbers, force quoting when you write the csv.

```
import csv

df.to_csv('./test.csv', sep = ',', index = False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Understand that this is just a hint. The CSV spec is minimal and apps do whatever they want.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working, I got the same problem

Answer (score -1):

What are your dtypes? `df.dtypes`

You might have to change your dtypes to strings if they are not currently so they save in the correct format. Otherwise something might be happening within excel if you try to open the csv.

Comment: That won't fix the problem because it's a CSV file, and CSV files don't contain type information (just "raw" data with no metadata).